# How to delete duplicate character and leave one occurrence only?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'm a beginner user in shell scripting, and I need to automate a process of removing duplicates for a bunch of files.
an example of my files :

```
1   Br  Atom
2   Cl  Atom
3   F   Atom
4   P   Atom
5   Al  Atom
6   Rh  Atom
7   Cl  Atom
8   Cl  Atom
9   Mg  Atom
10  O   Atom
11  N   Atom
12  H   Atom
13  H   Atom
14  H   Atom
15  H   Atom
16  H   Atom
17  Cl  Atom
```

What I'm looking for is to remove all the "Cl" atoms and leave only one "Cl", no matter which one.
I tried different commands like sort with uniq, and the command `awk '!a[$2]++'` atomos.txt, but I didn't get the desired result.
I need to remove specific duplicate atom whitout touching the others, and the order of other atoms must kept the same.
The desired output :

```
1   Br  Atom
3   F   Atom
4   P   Atom
5   Al  Atom
6   Rh  Atom
7   Cl  Atom
9   Mg  Atom
10  O   Atom
11  N   Atom
12  H   Atom
13  H   Atom
14  H   Atom
15  H   Atom
16  H   Atom
```

Comment: please update the question with what code you've tried so far, the (wrong) results generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output; also **1)** do you need to maintain the current order of rows? **2)** do all files have the same number of columns (3 in this case)? **3)** do we have to worry about case sensitivity issues (eg, is `A1` and `a1` considered the same)?

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close. Try:

```
awk '$2 != "Cl" || !dup++'
```

which will print the first Cl and remove the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt need rework to treat `Cl` and not-`Cl` differently, let `file.txt` content be

```
1   Br  Atom
2   Cl  Atom
3   F   Atom
4   P   Atom
5   Al  Atom
6   Rh  Atom
7   Cl  Atom
8   Cl  Atom
9   Mg  Atom
10  O   Atom
11  N   Atom
12  H   Atom
13  H   Atom
14  H   Atom
15  H   Atom
16  H   Atom
17  Cl  Atom
```

then

```
awk '$2=="Cl"?!a[$2]++:1' file.txt
```

output

```
1   Br  Atom
2   Cl  Atom
3   F   Atom
4   P   Atom
5   Al  Atom
6   Rh  Atom
9   Mg  Atom
10  O   Atom
11  N   Atom
12  H   Atom
13  H   Atom
14  H   Atom
15  H   Atom
16  H   Atom
```

Explanation: I used so called ternary operator which syntax is *condition*`?`*valueiftrue*`:`*valueiffalse*, so if we deal with `Cl` then use piece of code you already crafted, otherwise `1` i.e. do print.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility with `awk` can be:

```
awk '!f; $2=="Cl" {f=1;next} f' file
1   Br  Atom
2   Cl  Atom
3   F   Atom
4   P   Atom
5   Al  Atom
6   Rh  Atom
9   Mg  Atom
10  O   Atom
11  N   Atom
12  H   Atom
13  H   Atom
14  H   Atom
15  H   Atom
16  H   Atom
```

or `the desired output` where it appears at second (not first) time:

```
awk  '{f=1} $2=="Cl" {f=0;c++} {if (c==2) f=1} f' file
1   Br  Atom
3   F   Atom
4   P   Atom
5   Al  Atom
6   Rh  Atom
7   Cl  Atom
9   Mg  Atom
10  O   Atom
11  N   Atom
12  H   Atom
13  H   Atom
14  H   Atom
15  H   Atom
16  H   Atom
```

Other outputs:

- we control occurences of `Cl` with `c++`. So if its value is 2, we change `f` to true.
- But if what you need is it appears the third `Cl`, or the fourth `Cl`, change the `c` value in the comparison: `...{if (c==3) f=1}...` or `...{if (c==4) f=1}...`